# Ajuda com configuração do DbContext com o EntityFramework usando boas práticas

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, code-first, migrations

Tenho minha aplicação divida em camadas com `Class Library` e a minha camada com o `Entity Framework`, onde configurei o `DbContext`, é a `Repository`.

Minha classe herdada de DbContext:

```c-sharp
public class Context : DbContext
{
    private static string connectionString = "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=CRM; Integrated Security=True;";
    public Context() : base(connectionString)
    {
        // Set the auto versioning
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Migrations.Configuration>()); 
        // Gets or sets the database initialization strategy. 
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new Repository.DatabaseAdditionalConfigurations<Context>());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Pluralizing
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        // Non delete cascade
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        // Configure Pessoa
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add<Domain.Pessoa>(new Domain.PessoaTypeConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    #region DbSet´s ...
}
```

Vejam que a primeira linha do constructor é para a auto migração da base de dados usando o `Migrations`: `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Migrations.Configuration>());`.

Esse é um bom momento do ciclo de vida da classe para essa linha estar? Ou ela deveria ficar fora, em outro contexto?

E também criei a classe `UniqueKeyAttribute` para configurar os campos que são `unique` em minha base de dados:

```c-sharp
using System;

namespace Domain.Attributes
{
    ///<summary> 
    ///A unique attribute 
    ///</summary> 
    public class UniqueKeyAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

E para que esse atributo seja traduzido no banco de dados eu adicionei a seguinte classe, que infelizmente não me lembro a fonte:

```c-sharp
public class DatabaseAdditionalConfigurations<T> : IDatabaseInitializer<T> where T : DbContext
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(T context)
    {
        var created = false;

        if (context.Database.Exists())
            created = true;
        else
            context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

        if (!created)
            CreateUniqueKeys(context);
    }

    public void CreateUniqueKeys(T context)
    {
        //Fetch all the father class's public properties 
        var masterProperties = typeof(DbContext).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        //Percorre cada DBSet<> do DbContext
        foreach (var item in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => masterProperties.IndexOf(p.Name) < 0).Select(x => x))
        {
            //busca o tipo de "T" 
            Type entityType = item.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            // Cria as chaves únicas
            var fields = from f in entityType.GetProperties()
                         where f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Domain.Attributes.UniqueKeyAttribute), true).Count() > 0
                         select f.Name;

            var uniqueKeys = "";
            foreach (string s in fields)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(uniqueKeys) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueKeys))
                    uniqueKeys = s;
                else
                    uniqueKeys += ", " + s;
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(uniqueKeys) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uniqueKeys))
                context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("alter table " + entityType.Name + " add unique(" + uniqueKeys + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Bom, primeiro eu tenho um problema. Agora que adicionei o controle com `Migrations` eu não sei em que momento eu posso colocar a configuração `Database.SetInitializer<Repository.Context>(new Repository.DatabaseAdditionalConfigurations<Repository.Context>());` para que o método `CreateUniqueKeys` possa criar as chaves únicas no banco. Como eu poderia tratar isso? Seria no método `Seed` da classe `Configuration` do `Migrations`?

Outra questão é que minha base foi criada automaticamente somente quando `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;` do constructor da classe Configuration do Migrations estava setado como `true`. Precisa disso mesmo, ou estou fazendo algo de errado? Ir por esse caminho é uma boa prática?

Lembrando aqui sobre a pergunta do local ideal para: `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Migrations.Configuration>());`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### ConnectionString na Declaração do Contexto

Não é uma boa prática. Ao publicar seu site em uma base diferente (como no Azure, por exemplo), o sistema já não funcionaria adequadamente. O ideal é você configurar seu contexto da seguinte forma:

```
public Context() : base("name=SeuSistema")
```

E no `Web.Config` da raiz, tenha essa configuração:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SeuSistema" connectionString=""Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=CRM; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

### Remover Pluralização de Tabelas

Isto não é exatamente uma boa prática. Apenas evita que o Framework pluralize suas tabelas, que podem ficar estranhas se você escrever o sistema em português (por exemplo, um Model chamado `Contato` teria um controller chamado `ContatoesController`).

A maneira fácil e simples de resolver o problema de pluralização em banco de dados é usando [`[Table]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Remover *Cascade Delete*

Isto também não é exatamente uma boa prática. É claro que o *cascade on delete* é uma opção perigosa, mas não usar esta opção pode criar inconsistências estranhas. O ideal é não permitir a exclusão de registros quem possuam muitos dados dependentes.

### `SetInitializer`

O comando apenas indica que todas as *Migrations* pendentes precisam ser executadas na inicialização do sistema (não requer o uso do comando `Update-Database`). Não exatamente é uma boa prática porque pode executar erroneamente *Migrations* automáticas, o que pode gerar resultados imprevisíveis em caso de alteração frequente dos modelos. Esta configuração não é necessária.

O fonte `Migrations\Configuration.cs` já é executado quando for executado o comando `Update-Database` e na publicação do seu sistema utilizando o método *Web Deploy*. O método `Seed()` já realiza inserções e modificações de dados mínimos da base e não é necessário implementar um `IDatabaseInitializer` inteiro para inicializações, a não ser que você precise de um comportamento muitíssimo específico que a inicialização normal não faz, o que acho muito difícil.

### `CreateUniqueKeys`

O MVC é projetado para uso de *Surrogate Keys*, ou seja, chaves primárias que já são únicas. A ideia de outras chaves únicas serve bem apenas se for do interesse do programador identificar duas colunas como chaves, sendo uma independente da outra. Para isso, basta usar decorar todos os atributos desejados com [`[Key]`](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/key-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Por exemplo, se tenho um modelo chamado `Fabricante` e não desejo que dois fabricantes tenham o mesmo nome. `Nome` não exatamente é a chave. Neste caso, uso [`[Index(IsUnique=true)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.indexattribute(v=vs.113).aspx).

<strike>Entretanto, ainda assim a criação de uma `constraint unique` vai contra a ideia do *Entity Framework*, que o banco de dados deve ser agnóstico e nem todos os bancos de dados suportam `unique`. Dentro da abordagem do MVC, ainda usando o exemplo de `Fabricante`, o ideal é conferir se não existe um registro que possua o mesmo nome do registro a ser inserido/atualizado.</strike>

### Automatic Migrations

Como já dito acima, o mecanismo de *Automatic Migrations* pode ser útil apenas se não é necessário um controle rígido do estado do banco de dados (por exemplo, se o escopo ainda não foi muito bem definido, se há poucos programadores trabalhando no projeto, e se o projeto está bem no começo). Em estágio de desenvolvimento, isto pode ser muito útil.

Entretanto, não é recomendável usar essa configuração se seu sistema já possui uma instância de produção. Neste caso, é melhor usar *Migrations* manuais, geradas pelos usuários.